# Is "webServiceURL" required for implementing Pass for Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

We want to distribute a coupon through Apple Wallet to our customers and we don't want to implement web service for updating Pass information.

I've seen the [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1) provided by Apple, where Pass doesn't need to be updated.

My concern is that in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1) **webServiceURL** is not marked as optional field, but a use-case of using Pass without web service is actually possible.

Comment: We've tested the case and Pass was added without "webServiceURL" field to the wallet. Note that "authenticationToken" must not be included in pass.json if "webServiceURL" is empty.

Comment: You are right - as long as you do not want to update the passes, a webService URL is not required.  Note however, that this means you will NEVER be able to update the content on the pass.